# how to print users of Parse in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, parse-platform, pfquery

I'm trying to print users loaded of Parse, but can't find the error in the code.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad { 

    [super viewDidLoad];

PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"User"];
[query orderByAscending:@"username"];

[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {

    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    }

    else {

        self.allUsers = objects;
        NSLog(@"%@",self.allUsers);

        [self.tableView reloadData];  }

    }];

}
```

Comment: What does not work as you expect ?

Comment: @user3360241 Would have to print NSLog (@"% @", self.allUsers );

I have users uploaded to Parse correctly and i can't understand why not print users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe [self.tableView reloadData] has to run on the main thread in order to update from inside this block.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

    [self.tableView reloadData];
});
```